# SO for Teams: unread filter seems broken, or the resulting stats message incorrect

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-for-teams

SO for Teams, when I click "For You" in the left menu,

[image]

, the filter "only show unread" does not seem to have an effect on the results, as "0 unread items" is *displayed* - does not matter, *is*, or *is not* that filter active.

[image]

[image]

I would expect that if the "only show unread" is not active (gray), the message in the top left corner should not contain "unread" word (in bold).

Comment: It is incomprehensible near *"does not matter, is not not that filter active"*.

Comment: "is *displayed*, without difference if the filter *is*, or *is not*, active"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *For You* queue, by default, will contain both read and unread items in it, and the unread items are not always at the top of the queue because the system for marking them as read is not the same as with the global inbox in the top bar (where opening it marks everything as read).

The count at the left tells you how many total unread items are available to view, wherever they are intermixed with already-read items in the list. It will always be the same number regardless of the toggle state, changing only with the filter you are applying.

The toggle at the right limits your view to *only* things you haven't read yet, making it easier to find them if you have a lot of already-read items above them.